# React scroll to bottom only works for the first time (demo inside)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I have a react project where I am trying to implement infinite scroll, But not sure why it detects bottom only once, from next time onwards there is always 1 pixels difference in values so it never matches with `element.clientHeight`

Below is code that I am using to detect scroll to bottom

`Math.ceil(element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop) === element.clientHeight`

Going forward I actually want to fire axios call 200 pixels before it reached to bottom so In the mean time I can fetch the data and append to bottom so user never have to wait for data to load.

I have created demo repo which has the same issue as my project [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-8ghki?file=/index.js)

Comment: Any clue will be helpful

Comment: Is there any alternate site where we can ask/answers questions ? Stack overflow seems like dry.

Comment: I've tried it with Firefox and Chrome and it seems to work correctly with both of them. Once I reach the bottom of the list, new data is always loaded and I can go on scrolling smoothly. Perhaps I got something wrong? Which browser are you trying with?

Comment: I am using chrome, I tried edge too. I stuck at 39.

Comment: You don't have to set listner on scroll. Put some div in bottom of page/container and listen itersection. (this is more peformence) If it will intersect then fire load new content what affect shift this diff to bottom out of screen. Agian if it will apear then load more. (you can set intersection observer root on any container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**element.scrollTop** - how many scrolled from top,
**element.scrollHeight** - element's whole scroll height (with content visible and invisible),
**element.offsetHeight** - current visible height

When scrolling down, **scrollTop** increases,

So you want to scroll down to the bottom,
in other words you want distance(height) moved from top plus height of element's visible part to be equal to whole element's height:

```
element.scrollTop + element.offsetHeight = element.scrollHeight
```

we can write this as:

```
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.offsetHeight
```

So if you want some action happen before reaching the bottom, just substract this amount of pixels from **element.scrollHeight**, for example for 200px:

```
element.scrollTop = (element.scrollHeight - 200) - element.offsetHeight
```

or like this to make it work even after we pass the distance:

```
element.scrollTop >= element.scrollHeight - element.offsetHeight - 200
```

Aditionally, as using scroll inside element (div) with ref, you probably want to add event listener to scrollRef.current, not window

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.loadList();
  this.scrollRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll, true);
}
```

and remove event listener on unmount

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.scrollRef.current.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}
```

This should work:

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-121oc?file=/index.js)